# UPDATE em várias tabelas com a mesma coluna?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Vamos imaginar um cenário onde eu precise dar um `update` em 10 tabelas diferentes na mesma coluna em todas elas atualizando um determinado dado, a sintaxe abaixo irá funcionar?

```
UPDATE tab1, tab2, tab3... SET id_usuario = 'novo id' WHERE id_usuario = 'id antigo'
```

Todas as tabelas possuem a mesma coluna `id_usuario`, esse é uma pergunta meramente por curiosidade.

Comment: Se essa informação não pode ser "adivinhada", ela não é adequada. De qualquer forma, faz isso em 10 tabelas. Até tem como criar um *script* para tentar "automatizar" isso, mas dará mais trabalho que fazer na mão com ^C ^V. Na verdade se não tiver um padrão claro de mudança, sequer conseguirá algum resultado.

Comment: Antes eu usava sequências aleatórias de 9 números para criar o ID do usuário, mas ai li um pouco sobre UUID e me pareceu mais seguro usar um ID mais complexo e mais difícil de ser adivinhado mentalmente, por isso quero fazer o update

Answer (score 1):

Esse select vai criar um conjunto de update para todas as tabelas que se encaixe na condição do where. Ai você copia o resultado que serão vários update, cola no workspace e roda.

```
 select 'update '||owner||'.'||table_name|| 
           ' set '||column_name||'= **VALOR_SET** '||
         ' where '||column_name||' in (**VALOR_ATUAL**);'
      from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS where column_name = '**COLUNA**';
```

Comment: Esta resposta foi sinalizada como de baixa qualidade devido ao tamanho ou conteúdo. Por favor, se possível e se esta for uma solução ao problema, explique melhor como você o resolveu. O código pode ser trivial para você, mas para outros usuários pode não ser.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um inner join no seu update assim atualizar várias tabela ao mesmo tempo.

```
UPDATE TABELA1 
SET 
    A.Campo = 'Valor',
    B.Campo = 'Valor',
    C.Campo = 'Valor'
FROM TABELA1 A
INNER JOIN TABELA2 B on B.Campo = A.Campo
INNER JOIN TABELA3 C on C.Campo = B.Campo
```

Aí só você aplicar a lógica correta ao seu cenário.
Abra uma transação e faça o teste e caso seja o precise efetive a transação

Comment: Poderia fazer um exemplo adicionando mais tabelas, se possível?

Comment: Pronto @LeoLetto, isso irá funcionar por exemplo com três tabelas.