# UPDATE em duas tabelas PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

No meu banco de dados tenho uma tabela chamada

**cadastro**

- id_cadastro
- nome_user
- email_user
- idade_user
- sobre_user
- fb_user
- tt_user
- in_user
- avatar_user

Essas são as informações que eu uso para o login. Porém após ele se cadastrar nessa tabela o usuário é redirecionado para uma página aonde seleciona se é pessoa fisica ou juridica, contendo outras informações

**pessoa_fisica**

- id_fisica
- id_user
- cpf_user
- rg_user
- telefone_user
- celular_user
- cep_user
- cidade_user
- estado_user
- endereco_user
- numero_user
- bairro_user

A tabela pessoa_juridica muda só o campo para cnpj, inscrição estadual e municipal, de resto é igual. Porém quando o usuário vai atualizar as informações ele precisa atualizar essas duas tabelas e eu não sei como fazer dois UPDATES em um arquivo php. Porque estou usando apenas um form

**formulario**

```
<form method="post" action="php/atualizarFisica.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Nome Completo <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="nome" class="form-control" type="text"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['nome_user']; ?>" required>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>E-mail <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email_user']; ?>" required>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Data Nascimento <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input placeholder="" name="idade" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['idade_user']; ?>">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Telefone <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="telefone" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_fisica['telefone_user']; ?>">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Celular <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="cel" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_fisica['cel_user']; ?>">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 mg-t">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Sobre você: </label>
         <textarea cols="6" name="sobre" rows="8" placeholder="" class="form-control"><?php echo $_SESSION['sobre_user']; ?></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="heading-inner">
         <p class="title">Informações Pessoais</p>
      </div>
   </div>                 

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>CPF <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="cpf" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_fisica['cpf_user']; ?>">
      </div>
   </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>RG <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="rg" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_fisica['rg_user']; ?>">
      </div>
   </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Estado <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="estado" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_fisica['estado_user']; ?>">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Cidade <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="cidade" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_fisica['cidade_user']; ?>">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>CEP <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="cep" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_fisica['cep_user']; ?>">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Endereco <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="endereco" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_fisica['endereco_user']; ?>">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Numero <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="numero" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_fisica['numero_user']; ?>">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Bairro <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input placeholder="" name="bairro" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_fisica['bairro_user']; ?>">
      </div>
   </div>                   

   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="heading-inner">
         <p class="title">Senha</p>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Nova Senha </label>
         <input placeholder="" name="senha" class="form-control" type="password">
      </div>
   </div> 

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Confirma Nova Senha </label>
         <input placeholder="" name="senha" class="form-control" type="password">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="heading-inner">
         <p class="title">Mídias Sociais</p>
      </div>
   </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fb" placeholder="Facebook" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['fb_user']; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control border-field" name="tt" placeholder="Twitter" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['tt_user']; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['in_user']; ?>" class="form-control border-field" name="in" placeholder="Instagram" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 mg-t">
    <img src="images/users/<?php echo $_SESSION['avatar_user']; ?>" alt="" class="profile-img img-responsive" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 mg-t">   
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputFile">Imagem Perfil</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="avatar[]" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
      <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Caso queira alterar sua imagem de perfil basta clicar no botão acima.</small>
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <button name="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Salvar </button>
   </div>

</form>
```

**atualiza.php**

```
    <?php

    session_start();
    require_once('conexao/conexao.php');

    $id_user = $_SESSION['id_cadastro'];

    if(!empty($_POST['nome'])
    && !empty($_POST['email'])
    && !empty($_POST['telefone'])
    && !empty($_POST['cpf'])
    && !empty($_POST['rg'])){

        $nome       = $_POST['nome'];
        $email      = $_POST['email'];
        $idade      = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$_POST['idade'])));
        $telefone   = $_POST['telefone'];
        $cel        = $_POST['cel'];
        $sobre      = $_POST['sobre'];
        $cpf        = $_POST['cpf'];
        $rg         = $_POST['rg'];
        $estado     = $_POST['estado'];
        $cidade     = $_POST['cidade'];
        $cep        = $_POST['cep'];
        $endereco   = $_POST['endereco'];
        $numero     = $_POST['numero'];
        $bairro     = $_POST['bairro'];
        $senha      = ($_POST['senha'])?md5($_POST['senha']):false;
        $fb         = $_POST['fb'];
        $tt         = $_POST['tt'];
        $in         = $_POST['in'];
        $avatar     = $_FILES['avatar'];

        /* Descobrir se o email já existe */
        $iguais = "SELECT * FROM cadastro 
                    WHERE email_user LIKE '%{$email}%' 
                    AND id_user != {$id_user}";
        $iguais_query = mysql_query($iguais, $con);
        $row_iguais = mysql_fetch_assoc($iguais_query);

        if (mysql_num_rows($iguais_query) > 0) {
            $_SESSION['aviso'] = "O Email $email ja esta sendo usado";
            header('location: ../user-edit-profile.php');
            exit;
        } else{

            $update = "UPDATE cadastro
                        SET 
                            A.nome_user     = '{$nome}',
                            A.email_user    = '{$email}',
                            A.idade_user    = '{$idade}',
                            A.sobre_user    = '{$sobre}',";
            if($senha){
                $update .= "A.senha_user    = '{$senha}',";
            }
                $update .= "A.fb_user       = '{$fb}',
                            A.tt_user       = '{$tt}',
                            A.in_user       = '{$in}',
                            B.cpf_user      = '{$cpf}',
                            B.rg_user       = '{$rg}',
                            B.estado_user   = '{$estado}',
                            B.cidade_user   = '{$cidade}',
                            B.cep_user      = '{$cep}',
                            B.endereco_user = '{$endereco}',
                            B.numero_user   = '{$numero}',
                            B.bairro_user   = '{$bairro}',
                            B.telefone_user = '{$telefone}',
                            B.celular_user  = '{$cel}'
                            FROM cadastro A
                            INNER JOIN pessoa_fisica B ON B.id_user = A.id_cadastro
                            WHERE A.id_cadastro = '{$id_user}'";

            $executaUp = mysql_query($update, $con);

            if(mysql_affected_rows($con) > 0){
                $_SESSION['certo'] = "Atualizado com sucesso";
                header('location: ../user-dashboard.php');
                exit;
            } else{
                echo "Ocorreu um erro na atualização das informações";
                print_r($update);
            }

        } //ELSE UPDATE SEM AVATAR


    } else{
        $_SESSION['aviso'] = "Preencha os campos necessários.";
        header('location: ../user-edit-profile.php');
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Aqui só está fazendo o UPDATE na tabela **cadastro**, quero saber como fazer o UPDATE na tabela **pessoa_fisica** se o usuário alterar algum campo relacionado aquela tabela.

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176946/update-em-v%C3%A1rias-tabelas-com-a-mesma-coluna?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia fazer um INNER JOIN (**juntar tabelas**) efetuando um relacionamento entre as entidades pela chave primaria da tabela cadastro com a chave estrangeira da tabela pessoa física e efetuar o update de uma vez só.

Segue um exemplo:

```
UPDATE TABELA1 
SET 
   A.Campo = 'Valor',
   B.Campo = 'Valor',
   C.Campo = 'Valor'
FROM TABELA1 A
INNER JOIN TABELA2 B on B.Campo = A.Campo
INNER JOIN TABELA3 C on C.Campo = B.Campo
```

Eu acredito que no seu script a chave primária da tabela cadastro seja id_cadastro e deva ser repetir como chave estrangeira na tabela pessoa física como id_user então seria por esses campos que deveria gerar seu relacionamento.

PS: Atenção que ao modelar tabelas (tabela = entidade) aonde a chave primária de uma tabela se relaciona com outra entidade como chave estrangeira esta deveria ter o mesmo nome no campo (atributo), portanto desaconselho a prática de nomear um campo(atributo) como id_cadastro e repetir o mesmo campo(atributo) na tabela pessoa física como id_user isso gera confusão. Mas é uma prática que de início não damos muito atenção.

Espero que minha resposta seja útil ao seu entendimento.

**Atualização**

Para que possa ser resolvido o problema é necessário tomar algumas medidas para isolar a causa. Não se programa sem **errar**. Por isso é tão fundamental as mensagens de **err e warning**

Repare esse código abaixo:

> A.nome_user     = '{$nome}',

Ao invés disso faça apenas isso:

> A.nome_user     = '".$nome."',

Envolvido com aspas simples, no caso em que a variável que está inserindo no atributo (campo) seja uma string do tipo **(CHAR E VARCHAR)**,já no caso de variáveis do tipo inteira **(INT)** na há necessidade de aspas simples envolvendo a concatenação, apenas aspas duplas finalizando uma string para concatenar uma variável no meio dela.

Exemplo de uso :

```
$update = "UPDATE cadastro SET  A.nome_user = '".$nome."' FROM CADASTRO 
A WHERE A.id_cadastro = ".$id_user.";
```

Você defini que para o update ter sido um sucesso o numero de linhas afetadas após a execução da querie tem que ser maior que zero. Isto está corretíssimo!

> if(mysql_affected_rows($con) > 0){

No entanto não postou o código de conexão com o banco de dados e nem muito menos sabemos se as configurações de seu servidor tem a exibição de erros ativada ([Error Reporting](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php)) geralmente para se descobrir um erro deve-se depura-lo por isso que pedi em comentário para que coloca-se antes do seu if o comando :

```
echo mysql_error();
if(mysql_affected_rows($con) > 0){
```

Para que se existir qualquer erro de sintaxe em sua querie, definida na variavél **$update** ele reportasse

> Por fim como se depura um código? Instruções : **exit , echo, print_r **

Você reporta que ao executar seu código nenhum erro é emitido e portanto, se suas configurações estão corretas e o php está configurado para emitir avisos e erros e mysql_affected_rows é igual a zero ao final da execução deduzimos que o problema está sobre a querie que é definida na variável $update. Nesse caso a forma correta de descobrir é imprimindo o valor da variável concatenada **$update** e em seguida parar a execução do código com o comando exit. Portanto bastaria antes dessa linha fazer :

```
 echo $update; exit;
 $executaUp = mysql_query($update, $con);
```

> Repare que como utilizei o exit antes do mysql_query este não ira ser executado apenas a impressão da querie que existe na variável **$update**.Mediante a impressão da querie você poderia pegar e rodar o sql diretamente em seu phpmyadmin e verificar qual erro está sendo reportado e fazer as devidas correções. Caso contrário você pode ir utilizando o echo , print_r (**em casos de array ou objeto**) e o exit para ir parando o código linha a linha para entender o problema.

Esse texto é de extrema importância não se programa sem **erros**. Se não entender como se depura de forma organizada seu código até ter todo entendimento da lógica implementada não se **PROGAMA**, **copia-se** e **cola** e disso o mercado tá cheio!

Abraços Salomão

Comment: Eu fiz do jeito que você sugeriu não funcionou.

Comment: O que deu errado ? Atualiza sua pergunta poste o código do que fez.

Comment: Pronto atualizei o código php

Comment: Luis qual erro que dá ?

Comment: Embaixo dessa linha  $executaUp = mysql_query($update, $con);
coloque echo mysql_error(); e pegue o erro. Sem uma mensagem de erro é impraticavél depurar o código.

Comment: Eles está entrando direto no `else`.

Comment: Não apareceu nenhum erro, ele só cai direto aqui 
 `else{
                echo "Ocorreu um erro na atualização das informações";
                print_r($update);
            }`

Answer (score 2):

Quando se deseja realizar mais de uma query ou várias, e que estes dados são relacionados ou uma operação depende da outra, é recomendado transações sql.

Um exemplo em que eu preciso atualizar minha tabela pf e ao mesmo tempo quero atualizar as informações da tabela pj com os dados de pf.
As tabelas pf e pj são respectivamente para manter dados de pessoas físicas e pessoas jurídicas:

- Tabela pf

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Tabela pj

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código de nosso exemplo:**

Conexão com o banco de dados MySQL:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$porta = 3306;
$user = 'root';
$senha = '';
$database = 'test';

$conn = new mysqli($host,$user, $senha, $database, $porta);

if (!$conn){
    echo "Falha ao conectar banco de dados, verifique suas configurações.";
}
```

No código abaixo em php eu adiciono em variáveis (que numa boa prática seriam enviadas pela view, isso é um simples exemplo), onde se passa nome, login e id de uma pessoa física em que se deseja alterar os dados:

```
$nome = "Luiz Fernando";
$login = "luiz_fernando";
$id = 1;
```

Após utilizamos a função [mysqli_autocommit](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.autocommit.php), ela retorna valor TRUE ou FALSE e tem dois parâmetros necessários:

1. variável de conexão (no nosso exemplo $conn)
2. valor booleano para autocommit (no nosso caso FALSE, para que não seja realizado autocommit, lembre-se que se a transação falhar, teremos que desfazer as alterações para não afetar os dados)

Ainda vamos usar uma variável $erro com valor inicial 0 para sabermos se ocorreu erro na transação.

```
mysqli_autocommit($conn, FALSE);
$erro = 0;
```

Passaremos nossas querys e iremos testar se ocorre falha na execução das querys e se ocorrer iremos adicionar a nossa variável $erro. Se após os testes a variável $erro se manter com valor 0, não ocorreu erro e podemos executar o [mysqli_commit](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.commit.php) e de fato aplicar em nosso banco de dados as alterações ( e exibimos uma mensagem de sucesso).

Caso contrário, ocorrendo erro iremos executar a função [mysqli_rollback](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.rollback.php) para retornar a transação e desfazer qualquer alteração. Ainda iremos imprimir uma mensagem e quantos erros ocorreram:

```
$query1 = "update tb_pf set nome = '$nome', login = '$login' where id = $id";
$query2 = "update tb_pj set responsavel = '$nome', login = '$login' where fk_pf = $id";

if (!mysqli_query($conn, $query1))
    $erro++;
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $query2))
    $erro++;

if ($erro == 0) {
    mysqli_commit($conn);
    echo "\n Transação realizado com sucesso, dados atualizados!";
} else {
    mysqli_rollback($conn);
    echo "\n Ocorrem $erro erro(s) na transação e não foi possível atualizar os dados.";
}
```

Ao executarmos este script php, teremos como resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui o código completo:

```
<?php
// Dados para conexão ao banco de dados
$host = 'localhost';
$porta = 3306;
$user = 'root';
$senha = '';
$database = 'test';
// Variável de conexão ao banco de dados utilizando a função php mysqli
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $senha, $database, $porta);
// Teste de conexão
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Falha ao conectar banco de dados, verifique suas configurações.";
}

echo "MYSQLI COM PHP <br><br>";
// Variáveis com dados para alteração
$nome = "Luiz Fernando";
$login = "luiz_fernando";
$id = 1;
// Definição da função mysqli_autocommit
mysqli_autocommit($conn, FALSE);
$erro = 0;
// Querys
$query1 = "update tb_pf set nome = '$nome', login = '$login' where id = $id";
$query2 = "update tb_pj set responsavel = '$nome', login = '$login' where fk_pf = $id";
// Teste de execução das querys
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $query1))
    $erro++;
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $query2))
    $erro++;
// Se não ocorrer erros executamos o commit para o banco de dados caso contrários desfazemos qualquer alteração
if ($erro == 0) {
    mysqli_commit($conn);
    echo "Transação realizada com sucesso, dados atualizados!";
} else {
    mysqli_rollback($conn);
    echo "Ocorrem $erro erro(s) na transação e não foi possível atualizar os dados.";
}
```

Lembrando que este foi um exemplo só para demonstrar como pode ser feito, as tabelas, informações nas variáveis e sua captura, passagem de variáveis para query não correspondem um bom código na prática (viso apenas demonstrar a função). Existe também a função [mysqli_begin_transaction](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) com mais opções e melhor, para se trabalhar com transações de banco mysql e php.